# How to add custom URL to existing custom post type permalink?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have custom post type called `podcast` and another one called `episode` which has a taxonomy called `tag` for adding tags.

The `podcast` template shows the description of the podcast with a list of all it's episodes. I uses a permalink structure like `mysite.com/podcast/mypodcast` and a custom query to filter the list of shown episodes like `mysite.com/podcast/mypodcast?tag=2021`

Now I want to use clean URLs to filter the episodes and change the URL to `mysite.com/podcast/mypodcast/2021`. This URL has to call the same `podcast` template (as the URL `mysite.com/podcast/mypodcast` does), the filtering is done internally by the template file.

I'm familiar with [add_rewrite_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/), but can't figure out how to define it for this situation. I tried to add this to `functions.php`, but without success:

```
function my_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^podcast/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?p=$matches[1]&tag=$matches[2]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Or did I understand everything wrong and I have to do that with [WP_Rewrite](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/)?

Comment: Are you asking how to create custom rewrite for a custom taxonomy of a custom post type?

Comment: Actually I would like Wordpress only to know about this URL but serve the same custom post type template as when directly going to mysite.com/podcast/mypodcast. The rest I would handle from this custom post type template.